# For loop optimizing and making it faster

Tags: pandas, numpy

Hello I have a for loop that labels my stock prices to up and down, however, it takes long time to finish for 400K data points. I was wondering if there is any way to make it more efficient? Thanks for any suggestion

```
from tqdm import tqdm

df=data.copy()
n_days=100 # number of look ahead periods

fraction_movement=0.0005 # minimum return required 

df['Trend']=None
for i in tqdm(range(len(df))):
    try :
      for n in range(n_days): 
          if  df.loc[i,'close'] - df.loc[i+n,'close'] >= fraction_movement*df.loc[i,'close']:
              df.loc[i,'Trend'] =0
              break
          elif df.loc[i+n,'close'] - df.loc[i,'close'] >= fraction_movement*df.loc[i,'close'] :
               df.loc[i,'Trend']=1
               break
          else :
              df.loc[i,'Trend']=0
    except :
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that something like this could be faster, I havent tested it though not sure if it is equivalent:

```
def day_function(size):
list_size = size
prev = []
def fun(close):
    ret=0
    for n in range(len(prev)):
        if prev[-n] - close <= fraction_movement * close:
            ret = 1
            break
    prev.append(close)
    if len(prev) >= list_size:
        prev.pop(0)
    return ret

return fun

fn = day_function(n_days+1)
df['Trend'] = df['close'].apply(fn)
```